# Frequency offset estimation accuracy

Tags: digital-communications, estimation, ofdm, frequency-domain

To improve frequency offset estimation, we could:

1. Use the second order interpolation / equation in the frequency domain based on the coarse estimation fc, e.g. BPSK frequency offset estimation;
2. Zero padding the data set before doing FFT for the coarse estimation, e.g. OFDM symbol frequency offset estimation.

Are there any restrictions on when to use which method to improve the frequency offset estimation accuracy?

Comment: Well, what you want to do will depend on your SNR, your Doppler spread, the actual modulation schemes used on subcarriers (they often aren't even the same on all carriers), acceptable complexity and availability of known signal parts. There's really no general answer - you could fill a book about say frequency estimation for DVB-T, and another one about LTE, and another one about IEEE 802.11ac and another one about DSL...

Comment: Let's say two example: 1. satellite communication systems with QPSK; 2. OFDM in LTE. What could be the disadvantages and advantages to apply each of the methods to both systems?